# Relationship between rails models when one model is part of a mounted engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

The concrete problem:

I have a model that I want to have a has_many relationship incl. a dependent: :destroy property with Spree::Product of the spree commerce gem. However, my model should not be embedded into the Spree Engine.

Just using spree_product does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please give more details about the model. Have you try to use a ProductDecorator?

Comment: Its very straight-forward: I have a model that has_one Spree::Product and the Spree::Product belongs_to that model. However, rails throws errors as it doesn't seem to be able to reference these with each other due to the mounted Engine. PS: I tried the decorator, but "belongs_to :contract" doesn't work as it doesn't seem to find the contract model (same with path's where you use main_app.path but this does not work here)

Comment: Based in your comment then: `Spree::Product` should have a foreigner key to the Model its belongs. Did you create the migration?